# Migrating from nuspec to msbuild for nuget packaging

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

What is the equivalent property to use in msbuild for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files for migrating from nuspec to msbuild for creating nuget package.

Comment: I am really surprised no one is interested, even the view count is only 13 after half year...